# 'Could not find gem' error when specifying a forked version of a gem from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems

I'm trying to use a forked version of the ebay api gem (https://github.com/codyfauser/ebay/)

```
gem "ebayapi", :git => 'git://github.com/AutoRevo/ebay.git'
```

However when I run bundle install, I get the error.

```
Could not find gem 'ebayapi (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/AutoRevo/ebay.git (at master). Source does not contain any versions of 'ebayapi (>= 0) ruby'
```

The original gem works fine. (https://github.com/codyfauser/ebay)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure using the original repo works fine? There's no `gemspec` file in any of these repos. Very unlikely that any of them would work.

Comment: Hm. The original gem "ebayapi" bundles ok.

Comment: Were you using the original from github or pulling it from Rubygems?  There is a rake task that needs to be run in order to generate the `gemspec`.  I don't see that this would work without raking first.

Comment: I see, I assumed the github source would be the same. Can I make use of the forked "gem"?

Comment: In this case since there is no gemspec you can not point to it directly from github.  You could clone the repo and build a local gem then use that.  If for some reason you really want to point to github then you would need to build and then push the gemspec to the github repo.

Comment: Glad it helped; I've added it as an answer below if you want to help my karma ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no gemspec you can not point to it directly from github. You could clone the repo and build a local gem then use that. If for some reason you really want to point to github then you would need to build and then push the gemspec to the github repo.

Answer (score 2):

In this case since there is no gemspec you can not point to it directly from github. You could clone the repo and build a local gem then use that. If for some reason you really want to point to github then you would need to build and then push the gemspec to the github repo.  –  bigtunacan